# Is there a signed zero Integer in Java?

Tags: java, integer, zero, signed

I've learned that floating point number s have a signed zero in java. But I'm afraid `Integer` has not:

```
new Integer("0").equals(new Integer("-0")) // true
```

vs.

```
new Double("0").equals(new Double("-0")) // false
```

How could I store a sign with my zero `Integer` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot store a sign with Java integer primitive type.

Negative zero is an artifact of [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) representation, which stores a sign in a separate bit. Integers, on the other hand, are stored in two's complement representation, which has a unique representation for zero.

Comment: Thank you for illuminating :-) for the sake of completeness I'll leave another link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement