# GWT signed zero

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, signed

In Java I can distinguish between [0D and -0D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893756/is-there-a-signed-zero-integer-in-java?rq=1):

```
new Double("0").equals(new Double("-0")) // false
```

But apparently this seems not to work anymore after GWT transpiled my Java to JavaScript. I even get `false` in GWT dev-mode but `true` in GWT super-dev-mode.

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223359/are-0-and-0-the-same) that in JavaScript

```
0.0 === -0.0 // true
```

but

```
Object.is(0, -0) // false
```

How can I force GWT to use the `Object.is` comparision? Or is there any other solution to check if I got a negative or positive zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some more research, I came up with a solution using JSNI:

```
native boolean isNegative(double value)
/*-{
    return 1 / value < 0;
}-*/;
```

As `1/-0` produces `-Infinity` in JavaScript, this one works.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a new method using JSNI that uses `Object.is`:

```
public static native boolean compareDoubles(Double a, Double b) /*-{
    return Object.is(a, b);
}-*/;
```

Comment: +1 This seems to work but when I use `Object.is` in a GwtTestCase I get `com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (null)`

Comment: Hmm it's possible it won't behave the same under the hosted `HtmlUnit` browser.  I've certainly seen cases where behaviour is different. I've not got my environment set up to investigate at the moment, but i'll try and have a look this evening